# How to relation the child document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I refer a table to a child document in another table in mongodb?

For example, a video can only be added to the parent category or to a child category. Like video categorization sysytem of udemy website. I tried the mongodb refPath but I can't use dynamically at this system.

How can I do this query?

My video schema:

```
...
const VideoSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    category_ids: [
      {
        model_id: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          refPath: 'category_ids.model_name'
        },
        model_name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          enum: ['category', 'subcategory']
        }
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
)
module.exports = restful.model('video', VideoSchema)
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want! I am trying to make the categorization system of udemy.com. for example python is under both subcategories. Web development and data science. And I also want the opportunity to be under the main category of videos. For example ... 1- software development (main) -> python... and 2- business (main) -> finance (sub) -> python ... can be in both a main category and a subcategory of another main category. I tried this with 'refPath' but I could not provide this dynamic structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
When I added these two schemas, the query worked.

```
require('../models/category')
require('../models/subcategory')
```

And then run the find method with populate.

```
// ...
require('../models/category')
require('../models/subcategory')

Video.find({
      user_id: req.body.user_id
    })
      .populate({
        path: 'category_ids.model_id'
      })
      .exec()
      .then((videos) => {
        console.log(videos)
      })
// ...
```